# Xamarin Android unzip file from SD card, after unplug System.IO.IOException thrown

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-sdcard, ioexception

I would like to unzip a zip file from sd card to /internal_Storage. It works very well without problem, proccess finished successfully.
The problem occurs when I suddenly unplug the card, then I got this exception:

Unhandled Exception:

System.IO.IOException: Invalid handle to path "/mnt/sdcard/Sounds.zip"

After application crashs.

```
string zipFile = @"/mnt/Sounds.zip";
string unZipSoundsFolderPath = @"/data/internal_Storage/Sounds/";
using (var zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(System.IO.File.OpenRead(zipFile)))
{

        ZipEntry ze = null;

        try
        {

            while ((ze = zipInputStream.NextEntry) != null)
            {

                if (ze.IsDirectory)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(unZipSoundsFolderPath + ze.Name))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(unZipSoundsFolderPath + ze.Name);
                    }
                    continue;
                }


                FileStream fout = new FileStream(unZipSoundsFolderPath + ze.Name, FileMode.Create);
                BufferedStream bfout = new BufferedStream(fout);

                try
                {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = zipInputStream.Read(buffer)) != -1) //THIS ROW DROPS EXCEPTION
                    {
                       bfout.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }

                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException exs)//HERE NOT CAUGHT EXCEPTION
                {
                    break;
                }
                catch (Java.IO.IOException jex)//HERE NOT CAUGHT EXCEPTION
                {
                    break;
                }

                zipInputStream.CloseEntry();
                bfout.Close();
                fout.Close();

            }

        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException exs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exs.Message);
            importIsSuccessful = false;
        }
        catch (Java.IO.IOException)
        {
            importIsSuccessful = false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            importIsSuccessful = false;
        }

        zipInputStream.Close();

}
```

I have done many things, but everytime when sd card is unplugged, application will crush. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When a using block exits, it calls the Dispose() on the instance it is 'controlling'. Your using block is around zipInputStream, so when the using blocks shuts down, the Dispose() method on zipInputStream will be called. It is possible that this exception is being thrown from within zipInputStream's Dispose method. Add a try block around the using block to test this hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used try-catch block around the using statement, missed it from my post. Unfortunatelly result is the same: System.IO.IOException: Invalid handle to path "/mnt/sdcard/Sounds.zip". I left using statement, kept try-catch, but exception wasn't caught by any of catch statements. This is the critical point: `read = zipInputStream.Read(buffer)`. Zipinputstream lost its path to zip file. Any of try-catch can't catch the exception, it's very strange.

Comment: You need to get a hold of the exception itself, so that you can examine its stack trace. That will tell you where the Exception is thrown from.